# ffmpeg segmentation filter don't works with strftime filename template

Tags: ffmpeg

I try to run ffmpeg with segment filter and timestamp filename template:

```
 ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 960x720 -i /dev/video0  -f segment  -segment_time 5  -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_format mp4 -strftime 1 out%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4
```

and i got error:

```
Invalid segment filename template 'out%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4'
```

I have read a lot of posts and questions in the internet with the same arguments (after input, which is specific) and people says that this works. What wrong with my command?

UPD: add full ffmpeg log

```
root@nanopiair:~# ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 960x720 -i /dev/video0  -f segment  -segment_time 5  -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_format mp4 -strftime 1 out%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4
ffmpeg version git-2015-01-22-f86a076 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 22 2020 12:02:39 with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-vdpau --enable-libx264 --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfribidi
  libavutil      54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
  libavcodec     56.  0.101 / 56.  0.101
  libavformat    56.  2.100 / 56.  2.100
  libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavfilter     5.  0.102 /  5.  0.102
  libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 2548.007454, bitrate: 248832 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 960x720, 248832 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
[libx264 @ 0x201bec0] using cpu capabilities: ARMv6 NEON
[libx264 @ 0x201bec0] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x201bec0] 264 - core 142 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[mp4 @ 0x2507bd0] Invalid segment filename template 'out%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4'
Output #0, segment, to 'out%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.2.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 960x720, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.0.101 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

Comment: Your exact command works for me. Show the complete log from your command.

Comment: Your build source is over 5 years old. Upgrade to 4.3 or current git.

Comment: I have builded ffmpeg-cedrus. Unfortunately, i don't find cedrus support in newest ffmpeg

Comment: Follow the procedure mentioned in [OrangePI: H264 HW encoding with ffmpeg](https://blog.danman.eu/orangepi-h264-hw-encoding-with-ffmpeg/#more-735), or use the less old repo mentioned at the bottom of the article.